# Firebase Firestore: Rules filtering read counts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

If I had 10,000 records and 5 of them have my email and my rules are

```
allow read: if (resource.email == auth.token.email);
```

Would I get a result of 5 documents everytime I just straight up read the `db.collection('x')`:

Would I get charged for **5** or **10,000** reads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not charged for documents that were not transmitted to the client.  If your query returns X documents, you will be billed X reads.  Security rules don't change this fact.

You should also be aware that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) (please read and understand that link).  Any query from a web or mobile client is **all or nothing**.  Security rules will reject access to a query if it doesn't request only documents that would be satisfied by rules.   The rules will not check every document to see if it matches the rule - that would not scale at all.  Your query needs to include a filter that matches what the rule would check.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could mark two answers as correct, both your answer and the one from @Frank are equally helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The rules don't restrict what gets read. Only the query in the code can do that.

If your query only reads the 5 documents that have your email address in their `email` field, you will be charged for those 5 documents.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could mark two answers as correct, both your answer and the one from @Doug are equally helpful!

Comment: No worries. Doug was slightly faster than me and wrote a longer answer, so he deserves more credit. :)